# Torment vs. normal for legendary farm

Tags: diablo-iii

With new patch(2.0) you have different difficulties and despite which difficulty you are on, you are guaranteed a legendary drop when you finish the quest for the first time. And you can reset quests to get this first-time reward. Also, it seems that all legendaries can roll a lvl 60 stats(got a few low level legendaries with 400-500 stats).

So the question is: which difficulty should I play for the most/best legendaries? Does *Torment* give you better drops? I can farm *Torment* without many problems, but it seems that *Normal* is much more rewarding in terms of legendary drops because I can just fly through it.

**EDIT**

It also seems that you can reset quests any number of times. So a small addition:
Will I get more/better legendaries if I finish the game 2-3 times on *Normal* than if I would finish it once on *Torment* difficulty?

Comment: @jonathan that question doesn't cover quest rewards, only "normal" drop

Comment: Where did you see a guaranteed legendary from a quest? I've only heard of the guaranteed legendary from Skeleton King (said to be moving to Diablo). This is rewarded from a drop not specifically from the quest to kill him.

Answer (score 0):

This is all from my own personal experience, so I may be wrong in some aspects. But I think for the sake of finding drops, it's the most efficient to do the highest difficulty level where you are still able to rip through mobs.  For instance, if you can one shot mobs on torment 1 and torment 2, there is no reason to do torment 1.  Reason being that while chance to obtain a legendary does go up per torment level, the health of the mobs also go up.  So if you start doing higher torments and your kill speed slows down significantly, the time to kill seems to offset the higher legendary drop rate.

As for which difficulty to start on, I think only Master and higher will let you find level 61 items and higher.  I can't log in right now and verify but I think that's the only difference (minus the usual increased exp, gold, MF).

Comment: At level 70 there will be legendaries exclusive to Torment, but at level 60 there is no difference in the quality of drops based on difficulty level.